# Non-Canonical Page in Sitemap Issue

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, canonical-link

I have 1300+ pages that have 'non-canonical pages in sitemap' issue based on Ahrefs.
All of the canonical URLs are DNS URL like this.
[Canonical URL screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZdF4.png)

I would like to set the canonical URL to be the same as the URL's page.
Is there any method that I could try? Thank you.

P.S. I'm using RankMath for the SEO tool.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se] and questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it in one of those places once you fix the screen shot problem.